# Как выбрать значения в нескольких listbox Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Имеется три listbox, из каждого берутся значения. К сожалению, когда я выбираю что-то в одном, в другом выделение пропадает. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было выбрать элементы сразу в трех listbox?

Comment: Возможно, это: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048609/how-to-keep-selections-highlighted-in-a-tkinter-listbox

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `exportselection=False` чтобы перестать убирать фокус с `listbox` на другой виджет

```
import tkinter as tk


def func(e):
    print(*e.widget.curselection())


root = tk.Tk()
b = [i for i in range(9)]

list_box = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection=False)
for i in range(10):
    list_box.insert(i, i)
list_box.pack()

list_box_1 = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection=False)
for i in range(10):
    list_box_1.insert(i, i)
list_box_1.pack()

list_box_2 = tk.Listbox(root)
for i in range(10):
    list_box_2.insert(i, i)
list_box_2.pack()

root.bind_class("Listbox", "<<ListboxSelect>>", func)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы не могли бы еще подсказать ,как сделать так, чтобы в listbox выбрать элемент в списке с помощью метода, а не по щелчку?

Comment: @ВладиславСахар что вы понимаете под словом метод?